# Stopping Screen Timingout - windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, time, lockscreen

I am Creating a Windows Phone 8.1 that display the time,
Quite basic but one thing i don't want it to do is allow the phone to look. 
Now sadly ApplicationIdleDetectionMode does not working anymore unless you do windows phone 8.1 Silverlight application. 
So i have used.

```cs
var displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive();
```

now this works on its own and stops the phone going into the lock screen.

But my application does not work it goes it times out.

```cs
public MainPage()
    {
        var displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
        displayRequest.RequestActive(); 

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;



        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string time = String.Format("{0:T}", datetime);
        timeTXTblock.Text = time;

        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

        dt.Tick += (s, e) => { updateTime(); };

        dt.Start();
    }

    public void updateTime()
    {
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string time = String.Format("{0:T}", datetime);
        timeTXTblock.Text = time;
        return;
    }
```

I feel it might have to do with the tick on why it might be causing it to fail. Any idea why this might be and any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DisplayRequest is going out of scope as it is only active in the constructor. Define it within the class:

```
DisplayRequest displayRequest;

public MainPage()
    {
        displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
        displayRequest.RequestActive(); 
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much that has fixed the problem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it worked. Then screen did not locked.
DisplayRequest ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx ) is the way to go for non-Silverlight apps for Windows Phone.

Comment: What you mean it worked. I just sent it to my device again and it failed. It still times out and locks the screen.

Comment: Which version of WP are you using? I'm using a Nokia Lumia 920 with WP8.1 with Update 1, without Cyan. And what do you mean by times out/lock the screen?

Comment: Same as you. Nokia Lumia 920 with windows phone 8.1 update 1 dev preview.  What i want the app to do is display the time all the time. So my phone screen is set to timeout in 30 seconds after user inactivity. I want my app to not allow the and display it. 
But the code i found does not work. and it still timesout.
As its looking i might just have to do a Silverlight application.